# MySQL Cluster SQL node failover

Tags: mysql, high-availability, mysql-cluster

I'm trying to setup a mysql cluster for a web application to avoid having a single point of failure.  The Mysql documentation says:

> MySQL Cluster does not provide any sort of automatic failover between
>   SQL nodes. Your application must be prepared to handle the loss of SQL
>   nodes and to fail over between them.

The docs say the data is still accessible via the NDB API, but if my app is configured to point to a mysql server, how can i setup some type of loadbalancing/failover for multiple SQL nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failover functionality is provided by client connector libraries. For example, if you're using Java, your JDBC connection string can provide a list of MySQL host names. Here's documentation.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-config-failover.html

With ado.net and python, you'll need a setup called [MySQL Fabric](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/fabric.html).  This explains the connection string monkey business you'll need.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-fabric.html

Or, you can write specific application connection code that detects connection timeouts, and then tries another MySQL server.

Comment: Unfortunately links are no longer available